# How to get the wistlist_item_id in magento2

Tags: magento2.3, php-7.1

How to get the wistlist_item_id for particular customerId and productId in magento2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject `\Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist` Model class into your construct. Add this below code in your controller :

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;
class Wishlist extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist
     */
    protected $wishlist;

    /**
     * [__construct description]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context  [description]
     * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist      $wishlist [description]
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlist
    ) {
        $this->wishlist = $wishlist;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Default customer account page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute() {
        $customerId = '1';
        $wishListData = $this->wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true)->getItemCollection();
        foreach ($wishListData as $key => $value) {
            echo "Wishlist Item ID : ".$value['wishlist_item_id']."<br/>";
            echo "Wishlist Product ID : ".$value['product_id']."<br/>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```